# Facebook iFrame security error (document.domain) raised by hasPasswordField_

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, google-chrome, iframe

We have a project that use standard Facebook API used mainly for login and registration purpose. 
Since we use Sentry to receive error notification, the following one (in home page) occurs often:

```
SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.mywebsite.com" from accessing a 
frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com". The frame being 
accessed set "document.domain" to "facebook.com", but the frame requesting access did not. 
Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
at hasPasswordField_ (/en:1:368)
at hasPasswordField_ (/en:1:499)
at findPasswordForms (/en:1:173)
at global code (/en:10:27)
```

It's strange because the methods

```
 hasPasswordField_ / findPasswordForms
```

don't exist on the project code.

Because the error currently occurs only on

> iOS Chrome Mobile, version: 59.0.3071 | 60.0.3112

There is a Chrome internal component that is trying to access to the Facebook iFrame or is Facebook searching for some password fields on the webpage?

**UPDATE:**
After a further search, I found this post on Sentry GIT page:
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry/issues/5267
they suggest simply to ignore the error.

Any idea how to face it differently?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/ios/chrome/browser/passwords/resources/password_controller.js?q=hasPasswordField_&sq=package:chromium&dr=CSs&l=41

Comment: @JoshLee: I suppose that I can't apply any fix and since I use sentry to receive error notification, the only thing to do is just to add an exception to not receive it anymore. Have you the same opinion? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It says here that the bug has been fixed in version 61. https://crbug.com/709132